# XSLT copy node's child elements with pred

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:element name="rest">

       <xsl:copy-of select="node()/.[position()>2]"/>

 </xsl:element>
```

I just want to copy child elements of current node that i'm in but skipping the first two.
I also tried: <xsl:copy-of select="node()/.[name!='name' and name!='surname']/> which doesnt work, and code above also doesn't work.
<xsl:copy-of select="node()/*/> gives me child elements in child element of node()

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing input, your attempted XSLT and the expected output.

Comment: The child elements are selected with `*`, `*[position() > 2]` selects all child elements starting from the third one.